# EXCEL 2016 VBA: WorksheetFunction.Power() NOT returning a number

Tags: excel, vba, function, numbers

I have run into a similar issue with the WorksheetFunction.Power() function in EXCEL 2016 VBA to the one discussed here concerning the Fact() function:

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/468208-range-of-factorial-function.html

When I run my code, I am getting this error message:

[image]

For large numbers, the Power() function does not return a number. Here is a quick demo in the spreadsheet:

[image]

However, avoiding the Fact() problem was relatively easy: I just wrote a conditional statement like this:

```
If NTestvar < 170 Then
    KS = WorksheetFunction.Fact(NTestvar)
Else
    KS = 7.2574E+306
End If
```

HOWEVER, with so many base/exponent combinations, this is a bit more mutlidimensional. I tried this, but still get the same message:

```
    If IsNumeric(WorksheetFunction.Power(NTestvar, NTestvar)) = True Then
        KS_2 = 1 - ((2 / WorksheetFunction.Power(NTestvar, NTestvar))
    Else
        KS_2 = 1 - (2 / 1.79769313486232E+308)
    End If
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1041458/what-is-largest-value-number-that-i-can-store-in-an-excel-vba-variable

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I read that post before asking my question: That is why I use the number 1.79769313486232E+308 - I got that from that post. My problem is not a variable typing issue, though: I am not storing the the result in a variable in this statement where the error occurs:                                                                       If IsNumeric(WorksheetFunction.Power(NTestvar, NTestvar)) = True Then

Comment: is `KS_2` declared as a double?

Comment: The error occurs at the IF statement BEFORE the KS_2 assignment statement.

Comment: I think that IsNumeric has a limit. In testing it `1.0e309` throws an overflow error while `1.0e308` does not.

Comment: ah, the limit of a double on the positive is `1.79769313486231570E+308` Anything greater than that IsNumeric will Overflow.

Comment: Hi Scott, That definitely explains why the IF statement is throwing the error (which was a mystery to me before...). Thanks! Can you think of another way to evaluate when the numbers are too big before I invoke WorksheetFunction.Power()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to handle the error if it's thrown.  Wrapping `Power` in it's own function might be tidier too.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim KS_2 As Double
    On Error GoTo EH

    KS_2 = MyPower(100, 200)
    Debug.Print "KS_2 = ", KS_2
Exit Sub
EH:
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End Sub

Function MyPower(Base As Double, Exp as Double) As Double
    On Error GoTo EH
    MyPower = 1# - (2# / WorksheetFunction.Power(Base, Exp))
Exit Function
EH:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MyPower = 1#
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Function
```

Note that your function can throw other errors, eg if `NTestvar` = say -1000 it throws a "Division By Zero".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up generalizing Chris's approach and wrote this function that I can use in other parts of my application (For my use, the exponent is positive definite, so I did not need to worry about that eventuality). Many thanks Chris!! Your approach was the way to go!!

```
Function MyPower(Base As Variant, Exp As Variant) As Double
    On Error GoTo MyPowerErr
    MyPower = WorksheetFunction.Power(Base, Exp)
    Exit Function
MyPowerErr:
    MyPower = 1.79769313486232E+307
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! That is an important line. I have added it above.